# Change List inside a for loop

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I'm trying to modify a list inside a for value

```
for (int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++) {
    if(someCircunstances)
        theList.remove(component);
    else
        theList.add(component);
}
```

I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with this method.
Is there any method to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably you do not have the right reference for the `component` object. How did you take this reference?

Comment: I do, it crashes when the fifth iterarion comes in, I've debugged an seen that the crash doesn't have nothing to do with the remove and add functions

Comment: You need to reverse the for loop to start from Count -1 to 0

Comment: You mean `for(int i = theList.Count - 1; i  < 0; i++)`

Comment: What about the items that you add during iteration? Do you want to iterate over them also?

Comment: Nearly for(int i = theList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: And they could also cause more items to be added. Correct? If so, do you need to iterate over those?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm using the A* pathfinding, so I'm trying to search all the possible   estates(nodes) in my puzzle. I delete the nodes that have more cost than others.

Comment: Are you adding the same item twice? Or is `component` in `theList.add(component)` a new object?

Comment: You don't appear to be using the index variable `i` in order to do anything with a specific item (`theList[i]`) from the list.  Are you sure the code is right in this regard?

Comment: If i don't use a for and use a foreach instead, I can't modify the list inside the loop

Comment: Rather than using `Remove(item)` can you use `RemoveAt(index)` (assuming you know the index of the item you want to remove)?

Comment: I could try calling a function to know the index of the item.

Comment: It's often a better idea to create a new list and drop the old one.

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved by iterating backwards and using indexes instead of items:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if(condition)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    else
        list.Add(component);
}
```

Some explanation: when you iterating over collection you shouldn't change items in the scope. Iterators will detect that and throw (and in case of `foreach` you must use copy of list). But in case of using indexes (`RemoveAt()` method) and when iterating backward you are safe as for next iteration the scope doesn't include deleted items. `Add()` is adding to the end, therefore new item is never in scope.

---

I'll add few more solutions, which one is better decide yourself:

*Classical* foreach with copy first:

```
foreach(var item in list.ToArray()) // imho `ToArray` is better than `ToList`
    if(condition)
        list.Remove(item);
    else
        list.Add(component);
```

New list as result:

```
var result = new List<...>();
foreach(var item in list)
    result.Add(condition ? component : item); // not sure here, but should give you idea
list = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is also a bad practice to mutate the list while iterating over it.

This is an alternative:

```
theList.RemoveAll(someCircunstances);
```

Comment: I need to Remove "bad" nodes from the list, I can't delete it all.

Comment: Tamas is right, just write something like list.RemoveAll(item => someCircunstancesMatch(item)); If you want to do it manually, use a temp list to assign items to when the circunstances (sic) match. Then remove all items from the first list in the second list.

Comment: This answer is the right way. Note that the parameter to `RemoveAll()` is a predicate. The method could be more informatively named `RemoveAllItemsThatMatchThisPredicate()`. You might call it like: `theList.RemoveAll(item => item.SomeProperty == someTarget);`. Howewever, this does not address ADDING the items in the OP

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an out of range exception because indexes start on 0.

as stated above, one solution is to remove 1 from theList.count, and another solution is to initiate i at 1 instead of 0.

think of this: if your list has 1 element in it, the index of that element is 0, if you have 100 elements, the index of your hundreth element is 99.

you are thinking of the list like: [1][2][3], while it's actually [0][1][2]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are deleting values out of the list and then you iterate throught it again with an index which is already removed -> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

So to solve this i suggest you to split it up to two for loops:

```
for (int i = theList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(someCircunstances)
        theList.remove(component);
}

for (int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++) {
    if(someCircunstances)
        theList.add(component);
}
```

Comment: The crash happens before any item is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Tamas, that don't mutate the list while iterating , there is another way to achieve your point

```
 List<someType> ToRemove=new List<someType>() ; //some type is same type as theList is  
 List<someType> ToAdd=new List<someType>();

for (int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++) {
 if(someCircunstances)
     ToRemove.add(component);
 else
     ToAdd.add(component);
}

 theList=((theList.Except(ToRemove)).Concat(ToAdd)).ToList();
```

Comment: I need to use the added values inside the for loop so they can be used to find new nodes.

Comment: the new list will always with you inside the for loop to use , `ToAdd` as newly added elements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you need to be able to apply the same logic for newly created items.

You need to do something like this:

```
public void DoIt(List<MyObject> theList)
{
    List<MyObject> items_to_remove = new List<MyObject>();

    List<MyObject> items_to_add = new List<MyObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < theList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (someCircunstances)
            items_to_remove.Add(....); //Remove some existing item
        else
            items_to_add.Add(....); //Add a new item
    }

    if(items_to_remove.Count > 0)
        items_to_remove.ForEach(x => theList.Remove(x));

    if (items_to_add.Count > 0)
    {
        DoIt(items_to_add); //Recursively process new objects 

        theList.AddRange(items_to_add);
    }
}
```

The idea is that you insert the items to add and the items to remove in their own lists.

Then after the iteration, you remove the items that need to be removed.

After that you need to add the items to add. However, before doing that you need to run the same logic on them, and that is the explanation for the recursive call.

Please note that I am using `MyObject` because I don't know the type of your list. Use whatever type that you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the current index of the loop to remove the item from the lst, you can do this easily like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToList();
            var rng = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (rng.NextDouble() >= 0.5) // If "someCircumstances"
                {
                    numbers.Add(numbers[i]*2);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Assume here you have some way to determine the 
                    // index of the item to remove. 
                    // For demo purposes, I'll just calculate a random index.

                    int index = rng.Next(0, numbers.Count);

                    if (index >= i)
                        --i;

                    numbers.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", numbers));
        }
    }
}
```

This will also loop over all the numbers added to the end of the list. The value of `numbers.Count` is recomputed at each iteration, so when it changes, the loop will be extended appropriately.

(Offtopic) BONUS QUESTION: In the above code, what will be the average size of the list when the loop exits? And what would be the maximum size?

Comment: Since it is a A* path finding algorithm, the maximum size of the list will be 15^15.
This won't never happen because it will find the way earlier.
The only way to finish the loop is to accomplish some requirements.

Comment: @Patxiku I modified the code to show how to do it when you can obtain the index of the item to remove.

Comment: Removing at index will affect to the list structure? Will it be like an array and have a null value inside that index?

Comment: @Patxiku No, when you call `RemoveAt()` it removes that element from the list, and shuffles up all the remaining elements. The list will then be one element shorter than it was before you called `RemoveAt()`.

Comment: Then (as I underdtood), the loop could not check some values.

Comment: @Patxiku No, all values will be checked. There are two cases: (1) The item being removed is after the current index. In that case, no items will be skipped. Or (2) the item being removed is at or before the current index. In this case we need to reduce the current index to avoid skipping an item. That's what the `--i` is doing in my sample code above.